# kineticjs not respecting dragBoundsFunc to constrain dragging

Tags: kineticjs

I'm unable to get kineticjs to respect the [dragBoundsFunc](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-shapes-horizontally-or-vertically-tutorial) to constrain the dragging of two boxes horizontally and vertically in this [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vkL4/).  What do I need to do to make the below code work?

```
$(function() {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: $("#container").width(),
        height: window.innerHeight * 0.9,
        listening: true
    });

    var scrollAreas = new Kinetic.Group();
    var scrollBars = new Kinetic.Group();
    var scrollBarsLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    var hscrollArea = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 10,
        y: stage.getHeight() - 30,
        width: stage.getWidth() - 40,
        height: 20,
        fill: "gray",
        opacity: 0.3
    });

    var hscroll = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: 10,
        y: stage.getHeight() - 30,
        width: 130,
        height: 20,
        fill: "orange",
        draggable: true,
          dragBoundsFunc: function(pos) {
            return {
                x: pos.x,
                y: this.getAbsolutePostion().y
            };
          },
        opacity: 0.9,
        stroke: "black",
        strokeWidth: 1
    });

    var vscrollArea = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: stage.getWidth() - 30,
        y: 10,
        width: 20,
        height: stage.getHeight() - 40,
        fill: "gray",
        opacity: 0.3
    });

    var vscroll = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: stage.getWidth() - 30,
        y: 10,
        width: 20,
        height: 70,
        fill: "orange",
        draggable: true,
        dragBoundsFunc: function(pos) {
            return {
                x: this.getAbsolutePosition().x,
                y: pos.y
            };
        },
        opacity: 0.9,
        stroke: "black",
        strokeWidth: 1
    });

    scrollBars.on("mouseover", function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
    });
    scrollBars.on("mouseout", function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = "default";
    });

    scrollAreas.add(hscrollArea);
    scrollAreas.add(vscrollArea);
    scrollBars.add(hscroll);
    scrollBars.add(vscroll);

    scrollBarsLayer.add(scrollAreas);
    scrollBarsLayer.add(scrollBars);
    stage.add(scrollBarsLayer);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `dragBoundFunc` (and not `dragBoundsFunc`, note the `s`).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @RomainFrancois even if I to some extent agree with you, the op code is fine, he has just made a typo on the most important callback function. If he fix that everything will work.